# Flash drive not working on a particular RHEL machine

Tags: rhel

I have a 32 Gib flash drive. The first time I copied files to it, it failed with a write error and the drive was no longer recognized by the server. I ran a scan on it using Windows chkdsk, which fixed an error, but the server is still not recognizing it even though it works with Windows and other servers (and `fsck` on another server shows no problems). When plugged in, `fdisk -l` does not show it, /proc/scsi/scsi does show it, but also shows the other device entries from when I have tried the flash drive in different USB sockets:

```
Host: scsi5 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SanDisk  Model: Ultra Backup     Rev: 1.20
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
Host: scsi6 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SanDisk  Model: Ultra Backup     Rev: 1.20
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
Host: scsi8 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SanDisk  Model: Ultra Backup     Rev: 1.20
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
```

Every time I connect the drive, `dmesg` seems also to be running through a list of devices that are not currently connected:

```
sdd : READ CAPACITY failed.
sdd : status = 1, message = 00, host = 0, driver = 08
Info fld=0xa00 (nonstd), Current sd00:00: sense key Not Ready
sdd : block size assumed to be 512 bytes, disk size 1GB.
sdd: test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
 sdd: I/O error: dev 08:30, sector 0
 I/O error: dev 08:30, sector 0
 unable to read partition table
 I/O error: dev 08:30, sector 0
sdf : READ CAPACITY failed.
sdf : status = 1, message = 00, host = 0, driver = 08
Info fld=0xa00 (nonstd), Current sd00:00: sense key Not Ready
sdf : block size assumed to be 512 bytes, disk size 1GB.
sdf: test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
 sdf: I/O error: dev 08:50, sector 0
 I/O error: dev 08:50, sector 0
 unable to read partition table
```

Can anyone suggest a way to fix the drive? As I said, it works with other Red Hat servers. I am also worried that `/proc/scsi/scsi` is showing devices that are not connected -- why would that be?